# Array of objects returning null

Tags: javascript

I have this code that formats an array of objects, which is set out how I want it. However, when I go to return the output something strange happens. If I were to just return **alert_cache**, it returns null. But If I were return it like **alert_cache.workflow_steps** it returns the data needed.

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this?

```
if (alert_cache.length == 0) {
      alert_cache.workflow_steps = {}
      alert_cache.workflow_steps[keys.workflow_step] = { "errors": [], "last_error": {}};
      let alr = alert_cache.workflow_steps[keys.workflow_step];
      alr.errors.push(now)
      alr.last_error = {message: keys.message, url:alert.step_log_url}
}

return alert_cache;
```

Comment: How do you create `alert_cache` to start with?

Comment: *"However, when I go to return the output something strange happens. If I were to just return alert_cache, it returns null. "* The code above **definitely** doesn't return `null` if you do `return alert_cache`. It would fail (because `alert_cache.length` would throw a TypeError) or return non-`null`. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 2):

You're using `alert_cache` like an array *and* like an object. You're checking `length` (as if it were an array):

```
if (alert_cache.length == 0) {
```

but you're also assigning to a non-element property:

```
alert_cache.workflow_steps = {}
```

Note that doing that will not change `length`.

You haven't shown how you create `alert_cache` to start with, but if it's an array, and if you're then using it with something that only looks at its array entries and not at its other properties (for instance, `JSON.stringify`), it will be empty (**not** `null`).

Comment: Thanks man:

alert_cache is initially set as an empty array. Once I get this working correctly, there will be a following else statement to append to the array of objects. I'm appending non-elemental values to it, correct. Is there a better solution to what I'm trying to do so that when I return alert_cache it returns what I need?

Comment: @fellinlovewithaman - Returning `alert_cache` isn't the problem, that'll work fine -- unless whatever's using it expects it to *just* be an array and doesn't use its non-element properties. What you're doing is fine in JavaScript, but not fine in most other environments, and won't survive conversion to/from JSON (for example). If you'd put an MRE in the question, we'd be able to help you better.